# Is there a tutorial that shows how to use tabs and activities to pass values

Tags: android, tabs, extras

Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to use a tabhost and activities for each tabs content and pass values via extras. If so can someone post a link how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Intent.putExtra(..](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)):

```
intent.putExtra("keyName", "somevalue");
```

This method is overloaded and takes various types as second argument: int, byte, String, various arrays..

To get the data out use appropriate getXYZExtra(). For String this is:

```
getStringExtra(String keyName)
```

Comment: I had it like that but the second tab when it shows the second activity does not know the values are available   I have even read in another post that the intents are set when the tabs are built and extras can not be added. So how does one build a two tab app such that tab one is inputs and tab two is results